# Invoke a python script when an outlook email is received?

Tags: python, outlook, client, win32com

My requirement is to invoke a python script as soon as a particular email is sent to a specific address in outlook. I am using win32com outlook client in my script.

I am thinking of running the script indefinitely,  and keep on reading the received emails. But, there might be another better way to achieve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance,
Phani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something similar to this which uses poplib. from memory its pretty much:

```
import poplib
while True:
    email = checkEmail()
    if email['sender'] = 'senderiwant@domain.com':
        doJunk()
```

long story short, check out poplib, its got good stuff for checking/recieving mail